# Creating Weighted Average and 3 Year Average values based on Year Inputs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am hoping someone can help me come up with a solution to my problem.  I have a data frame that I'm looking to add 2 new sets of values based on the existing data frame.

1. Weighted Average to come up with a composite weighted average by stat (2014 = .4,  2015 = .4, and 2016 = .2) multiplied by the grouped stat (HR, R, RBI, SB)
2. 3 Year Avg (Same Idea as above, but just a straight 3 year mean of the 3 most current year)

I'd like the new data to be identified under the season column.

Here's the `data.frame`:

```
full_table_raw <- structure(list(playerID = c("abreujo02", "abreujo02", 
"abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", 
"abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", "abreujo02", 
"arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", 
"arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", "arenano01", 
"arenano01", "arenano01", "blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02", 
"blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02", 
"blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02", "blackch02"), season = c(2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), stat = c("HR", 
"R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", 
"HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", 
"SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", "RBI", "SB", "HR", "R", 
"RBI", "SB"), points = c(3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 
2, 1, 3), ranks = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
1), value = c(36, 80, 107, 3, 30, 88, 101, 0, 25, 67, 100, 0, 
18, 58, 61, 2, 42, 97, 130, 2, 41, 116, 133, 2, 19, 82, 72, 28, 
17, 93, 58, 43, 29, 111, 82, 17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
full_table_raw %>% 
  # add a new column with the weights to apply
  mutate(weight = ifelse(season == 2016, .2, .4)) %>%
  # group_by, and then compute your averages
  group_by(stat) %>% 
  summarize(
    average = sum(value) / 3,
    weighted_average = sum(value * weight))
```

Which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  stat  weighted_average average
  <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>
1 HR                83.8    85.7
2 R                258     264  
3 RBI              275     281  
4 SB                35.0    32.3
```

If instead of computing a summary you want to add `weighted_average` and `average` as columns to your initial data frame, you can simply replace `summarize` by `mutate`

```
# A tibble: 36 x 9
# Groups:   stat [4]
   playerID  season stat  points ranks  value weight average weighted_average
   <chr>      <int> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 abreujo02   2014 HR      3.00  1.00  36.0   0.400    85.7             83.8
 2 abreujo02   2014 R       2.00  2.00  80.0   0.400   264              258  
 3 abreujo02   2014 RBI     3.00  1.00 107     0.400   281              275  
 4 abreujo02   2014 SB      2.00  2.00   3.00  0.400    32.3             35.0
 5 abreujo02   2015 HR      2.00  2.00  30.0   0.400    85.7             83.8
 6 abreujo02   2015 R       1.00  3.00  88.0   0.400   264              258  
 7 abreujo02   2015 RBI     2.00  2.00 101     0.400   281              275  
...
```

Note that we can use a final `%>% select(-weight)` to remove the column `weight` that we added

Comment: 2 things: 1. How would you amend the weighting if the weights were 2016 = .5, 2017 = .3, and 2018 = .2?  Is there a way to store the weights in a separate list and multiply accordingly? 2. How would you do this so the result binds to the existing data frame and names the result under the season column to (weighted, and 3_yr_avg)?

Comment: 1. Use multiple nested `ifselse`: `ifelse(season == 2018, .2, ifelse(season == 2017, .3, ...))` 2. See my updated answer: you can use `mutate` instead of `summarize`, and you can choose the name of the new columns

Comment: I'm not looking to add new columns, I'm looking to add new rows.  I want to bind the results of weighted, and 3 year average underneath the existing column names.  The new rows that are binded would bind underneath the season column and be notated as "weighted", or "3_yr_avg"

Comment: Why are you trying to add new rows? it doesn't seem advisable. What would the `season` be for your new rows? What would the `stat` be? Summarizing results in a new data frame is most likely a better approach.

Comment: The `full_table_raw` data is going to be grouped by the season column so that there is only one corresponding value for each stat category by season.  For example, I want there to be one row that has season = 2014 with the HR value, another row that lists weighted for HR that applies the weights to come up with a composite weighted value for that stat.  With your approach, there are a ton of duplicate values listed in each respective column.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there are duplicates: it's much easier to work with. What you're trying to do defeats the purpose of data frame.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185177/discussion-between-jazzmatazz-and-aurelien-gasser).